# How to remove certain rows during a select operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base {
  attr_accessor: name
}

Foo.all
```

Foo currently contains ("A", "B", "C", "X", "Y", "Z")

I would like to remove certain Foo objects whose names are "X", "Y", "Z" from all Foo(s). How should I do this?

Comment: Add some details about how the list of rejected names is defined, there are lots of ways to do what you want but with some more context you'll get the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
Foo.where("name not in (?)",["X","Y","Z"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`Foo.where("name not in (?)",["X","Y","Z"])`

And I recommend you create a name index on this table to improve performance.

Like:

`add_index :foos, :name`

Comment: Warning: this WILL delete the data from the table.

Comment: Oops, i am sorry, if want to remove, just do it like your said.